# What is the error in code while using Google Javascript API to create an image popup map using leaflet

Tags: javascript, html, api, google-api, leaflet

I hope you all are doing good,
I'm trying to make a map which shows an image in popup when clicked anywhere on map, but the image it will popup will be extracted using geocoding which will involve JavaScript google map API.
But the thing is, its not displaying anything when I click anywhere/any location on map.

I hope this topic interest many people, Looking forward for your help :)

Information= File extension= .html, Mapping library= Leaflet, and Google map API.

**Here is the code:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Leafle Map</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.css"    integrity="sha256-kLaT2GOSpHechhsozzB+flnD+zUyjE2LlfWPgU04xyI=" crossorigin="" />
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha256- WBkoXOwTeyKclOHuWtc+i2uENFpDZ9YPdf5Hf+D7ewM=" crossorigin=""></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map" style="width: 1350px; height: 640px;"></div>
        <script>
            // setting map location and initiating a map variable
            var map= L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
            // adding basemap tile so that the map variable appears when opened in browser
            L.tileLayer('https://stamen-tiles.a.ssl.fastly.net/toner/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);

            // customizing the image shown when clicked at any location on map  
            map.on('click', function(e) {
                var latlng = e.latlng;
                var lat = latlng.lat;
                var lng = latlng.lng;
                var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + lat + "," + lng + "&key=AIzaSyD5m00mpDT_4zOOhYPpiEudiuwjP23OYSk";
                fetch(url)
                        .then(function (response) {
                        if (!response.ok) {
                          throw new Error("HTTP error, status = " + response.status);
                        }
                        return response.json();
                        })
                        .then(function (data) {
                          window.alert(data);
                        })
                        .catch(function (error) {
                          window.alert("Fetch error: " + error);
                        });
                        // .then(function(response) {
                        //     if (!response.ok) {
                                //     throw new Error("HTTP error, status = " + response.status);
                                // }
                                // return response.json();
                        // })
                    // .then(function(data) {
                    //     var placeName = data.results[0].formatted_address;
                    //     var photoReference = data.results[0].photos[0].photo_reference;
                    //     var imageUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=150&photoreference=" + photoReference + "&key=AIzaSyD5m00mpDT_4zOOhYPpiEudiuwjP23OYSk";
                    //     var popupContent = '<h3>' + placeName + '</h3><img src="' + imageUrl + '" />';
                    //     var popup = L.popup()
                    //         .setLatLng(latlng)
                    //         .setContent(popupContent)
                    //         .openOn(map);
                    // });
            });

        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Screen Display when clicked anywhere on map:**
[image]

I have tried checking if API is invalid but doesn't seems like that's the case. Also, when I tried just printing code till error showing line till "fetch(url)", if gives some alert but when I
uncommented even "function(data)" lines the screen gets blank(not even the base map that was showing in above scenario).

Positively looking forward for any solution or debugging to make this code workable from developers and problem solver of this platform :))

Comment: Learn to use `console.log` instead of `window.alert`.

Comment: I have tried that but that doesn't remove the error though as it is just another way to see errors